# Add XML header in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, literals

I have the following XSD:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="attr1" /> 
           <xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In the system, the XSD generates the following XML

```xml
<foo>
  <attr1>some content</attr1>
<foo>
```

What I want is to add a header, which I cannot do during file creation with a reasonable effort so I want to define the XML header in the XSD as a "string", to achieve the following output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
  <attr1>some content</attr1>
<foo>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, XML declaration prolog cannot be enforced by an XML Schema.